# Javascript memory optimization when array shifting

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have in my project history of changes.
History is an array consisting of objects where each object has 2 arrays.

So when I add history snapshot it looks like this (but in reality i'm not adding empty arrays):

```
history.push({   //new history moment  
    firstP:  [],
    secondP: [],
 })
```

And e.g. the array firstP consists of objects like this:

```
{
    color: "red",
    move: 1,
    ... and some other fields (max 14 fields if it matters)
}
```

firstP and secondP usually holds thousands of objects.
So each history snapshot is pretty heavy for memory.
So i added limit

```
const limitOfSteps = 50;
```

now after every push i check if length of history isn't greater than 50.
If it is i do history.shift();

But what i see in my memory is that even when shifting (removing first element in the array) used memory is increasing. The element is added to history when user do something in the react app so he can do as many changes as he wants to.

I know there is garbage collector but how does it work with arrays?
Shifting array should mean that the element is gone (and gone from memory too?)
But it's not gone immediately (If user will make changes quickly then the whole app
will be out of memory).

Changing the removed element (just before shifting the array) to undefined or null would make the memory free quicker?

Main goal is to use less memory... does anyone know how to?

Edit:
The array may be shifted even thousand times.

Edit2 (Maybe my question was all wrong? Maybe i should ask if when the whole array is removed ?)
It is all in the react app in the state.

Probably slicing the history (doing copy) is much more memory consuming, but it is inevitable because state is immutable.
My method to update looks something like this:

```
updateHistory = (newElement) => {
    const history = this.state.history.slice();
    history.push(newElement);
    if(history.length - 1 > 50) history.shift();
    this.setState({history: history});
}
```

Does it anything make sense?

Comment: [`unshift() "adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). It does not remove anything.

Comment: I mean "shift" sorryy. I edit the question

Comment: Can you show us the code that limits the array to 50 elements ?

Comment: OKay i updated everything, please read it ...

Comment: In effort to reduce your insane amount of overhead here I wrote some really lols concept code that should never see the light of day. https://jsfiddle.net/3ajuyqz1/5/

Comment: I guess is what actually matters is the code that populates `firstP` and `secondP` with "*thousands of elements*". How are these elements created? From where else are they referenced? Please post that code. The `history` array itself with barely 50 elements will not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is done automatically in JavaScript, it's not something that you have to manage yourself. This is also why you're seeing the memory increasing when shifting items from your array although you limitted the size to 50.

You can't force or prevent the garbage collection, but when it runs, it takes care of removing values without a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

> An object is said to be "garbage", or collectible if there are zero references pointing to it.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Associates to that approach you can try to remove variable reference. Example:

```
var a = 1;
var array = [a, 2, 3, 4];
a = null;
array.shift();

// or

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array[0] = null;
array.shift();
```